# Xamarin.ios appropriate location to ask for permissions

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I need to ask for permissions in a Xamarin.iOS Application with [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios). All the examples I've found so far are about Xamarin.Forms which I'm not using.

All the samples I have found so far are about asking permissions when pressing a button which is fine for experimenting but useless for a production application.

I have the following async code:

```
// TODO Move the permission requests to a more appropriate location?
var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
}
status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
{
    status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
}
```

I'm calling it from a ViewDidLoad async override.
The application crashes with the following output whenever I'm calling Permissions.RequestAsync()

```
2020-05-08 10:21:05.815 yaka[714:200964] error: * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/ios/release/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:4568, condition `array->len == 1' not met
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014e7754: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101065470: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x10123472c: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101064370: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014ab360: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1015ac108: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1015592a0: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101559224: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x10105f0c0: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014ab360: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014e7754: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101065470: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x10123472c: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101064370: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014ab360: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1015ac108: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1015592a0: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x101559224: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x10105f0c0: 8
[PLCrashReport] plframe_cursor_read_dwarf_unwind_int:131: Failed to find FDE the current frame pc: 0x1014ab360: 8
```

My info.plist contains the following about permissions:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>L&apos;accès est réservé au vidéoconférences.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>L&apos;accès est réservé au vidéoconférences.</string>
```

There must be an appropriate location to call this coded safely but I can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is not a good design to request the permission in ViewDidLoad . You could move them to method `ViewDidAppear` .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need specific code for iOS. That's the beauty of *Essentials*. It utilizes the so-called **bait & switch** pattern. In simple words - the exposed code is the same for each platform and during compile-time only the code that you need will be compiled. You can see the Permissions code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/master/Xamarin.Essentials/Permissions).

If you look ad the [Xamarin.Essentials.csproj](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/master/Xamarin.Essentials/Xamarin.Essentials.csproj#L92), you will see that in case the project targets iOS, only the cs files with suffix `*.ios` will be built. Then, on runtime, the appropriate code will be invoked.

Most probably, you are calling it in an incorrect place. Try calling it in `ViewDidAppear`, since this error sounds like Xamarin was expecting something to have been fully loaded/visible and it wasn't.

To sum up - you can use the code samples that you can find on the official documentation page on each platform without any issues. Just be careful where exactly you are calling them.